# SSIS: Is there a simpler way?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have 3 tables in an oledb database that I am pulling data from using SSIS packages daily to a mssql server. For the vast majority of the time this data is good and does not need to be modified, but about twice a month I get null values for brief periods that I want to replace with the last known good value or some other generated value. Is there a way to do this in SSIS without having to run several sql queries with CTE commands after the data flow task as I am doing now? CTEs work when there are small gaps like an hour or two, but if its more than that using CTEs cause deviation from the trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to replace null value with last good value then you can populate the cache of that columns "having good values" with key Columns for only last one month and then lookup the value using conditional splitter by checking null. but you can do so if the number of columns are small and there is not so huge data.

But in case of huge data you have to write a function and use that function in sql which return the same value in case of good value and in case of bad value search for last good value and return that.

Comment: in case you have a doubt. discuss with full scenario like no of column, updating a column with last good value for that column or update a last good values row etc.

Comment: Alright thanks, I was wondering if any of the stuff in the SSIS toolbox could do it, but it looks like SQL queries are the way to go.